# What is the best way to replace all non-null elements of a matrix by ones in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
% estimation of the jacobian sparse matrix
u_iterator=0;
s=eye(size(u),size(u));
for u_iterator=1:size(u)
    if u(u_iterator) >1e-5
       s(:,u_iterator)=1;
    end
end
```

I'm actually using this code to replace all the non-null elements of a matrix by ones and I let zeros where the elements are null. My question is:Is there a better way to do this by using a function of matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the logical indexing feature of MATLAB, i.e.

```
s = u;
s( s > 1e-5 ) = 1;
```

Of course

```
s( abs(s) > 1e-5 ) = 1;
```

or

```
s( s ~= 0 ) = 1;
```

would also work.

Comment: Or `s = double(logical(s))`

Comment: @Luis Mendo. True, In the same spirit one could also write, `s = double(u ~= 0)`